# Following controls were added but are not enabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to add the Windows Media Player component to my solution, but this message is displayed instead.

> The following controls were added but are not enable in the active designer. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework

I'm using Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 and .NET framework target is 4.5

I copied my DLL to the bin folder too.

Comment: I down voted, and close voted, because there is no way to reproduce your problem given the question. This can be fixed by providing implementation details and explaining what the error is.

Comment: @theMayer If you are using Windows 8.1 and VS 2013, add wmp.dll to the toolbox and check if that works for you. Do you have Windows SDK installed?

Comment: I unfortunately use win7. Can you at least post the error text? If you tried to post something, it doesn't show up for me.

Comment: @theMayer "The following controls were added but are not enable in the active designer. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework version."

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Created the solution two times in a row, worked without doing anything.

Comment: how to create solution two times in a row,

Answer (score 6):

When You create Windows Forms App there are two ways: (.NET Framework) and (.NET)
You should chose Windows Forms App (.NET Framework).

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest you to check if the version of the dll that you have imported is for 4.5 version of framework.  Maybe it's for an older version of framework.

If it doesn't help you try [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this guide.

As workaround I can suggest you to copy that dll in your bin/debug folder and then add references to the project from your bin.

Comment: I've used all the target versions, so I don't think that's the problem. Thanks for downvoting tho...

Comment: Hey friend, don't worry, I don't have downvoted nothing.

Comment: If I downvote I always leave a comment with the reason.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll Did you try following the steps in the guide that I have attached to the answer?

Comment: Sure, I was using that one. Still stuck on step 3 due to the error.

Comment: Same, found the workaround in another thread. Thanks for helping anyways.