# C#.NET Unable to add windows media player control to Toolbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to stream video and audio files from my website, using ASP.NET and C#.NET, developed in VS2012.

Currently, I'm streaming audio files programmatically; however, I have no visible player, which is a huge problem because I have no controls (play, pause, etc).

I have followed the following MSDN documentation in attempt to add this control:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx

Using this documentation, I'm not able to add the Windows Media Player control to my toolbox after right-clicking in toolbox, selecting Choose Items, COM Components tab, checking Windows Media Player checkbox, clicking Ok, then I get a pop-up message saying, "The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox, but are not enabled in the active designer: Windows Media Player. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework version." However, after doing so there is still no Windows Media Player control in my toolbox.

I'm using ASP.NET Framework 4.5.1.

Additionally, I have added all references to Windows Media Player in my project also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Following controls were added but are not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878153/following-controls-were-added-but-are-not-enabled)