# Windows Media Player in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-5, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a .NET 5.0 WinForms app in which I am trying to add the Windows Media Player. I am trying to add it to the Toolbox by doing ***Choose Toolbox Items*** -> ***COM Compononents*** which tells me ***the following controls were added but are not enabled.***

I wonder if I have some version compatibility issues and what should I do in this case?

Comment: Related: [Following controls were added but are not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878153/150605), [C#.NET Unable to add windows media player control to Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42706385/150605)

Comment: I've seen that, apparently, they are using .NET Framework whereas I am using .NET 5.0.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is to use the WPF `MediaPlayer` control in code,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Step 1: Open your project file and enable WPF,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Step 2: Initialize the control in code and play some file,

```
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace testwinforms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\someuser\Downloads\somefile.mp3"));
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

This works for .NET Core 3.0/3.1 and .NET 5/6.

Note that if you want to see the control visually, you need to use `ElementHost` to [bridge WPF/WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0).

Comment: I can't get that to work. Are you sure that's all I need? Surely I'd have to add the player to my forms' controls collection?
I also just tried using VideoDrawing, no luck.

Comment: @Veljanovski It works on my machine, an empty WinForms project created from `dotnet new winforms` with the changes listed above. If you cannot get that to work, you will have to show what exactly you tried (the detailed steps).

Comment: @LexLi cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control', when I try to add the player to this.controls.add(player);

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen Because the `MediaPlayer` control is from WPF and you cannot use it like any WinForms control. Why do you want to add it to `this.Controls`? I don't see a need.

Comment: @LexLi I don't see any way to add a media player to forms 6.0, I want to play a video file, suffering for a week!!

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen Use `ElementHost` to host a WPF control on your WinForms should resolve the issue, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: @LexLi It seems to be an excellent answer for these like all questions! You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score -2):

This page describes several ways to use the Windows Media Player control.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/player-control-guide

If you want to use Windows Media Player control, .NET Framework will be a better choice

Comment: What you linked is a WPF control, not the one this question is asking about (a COM control). Also the way you interpreted "Applies to" section is wrong, and the WPF `MediaPlayer` control is available on .NET 5, though irrelevant to this question.

Comment: ".NET Framework will be a better choice". But is it the only choice? Should I try and migrate from .NET 5.0 to .NET Framework?

Comment: Through reading the documentation, we can see that windows media player control is not applied to .NET 5.0 right now. Currently It will be a good choice to migrate to .NET Framework